# Hide scrollbar on contacts adapter?

Tags: android, scroll

I'm building an accessibility app and I Santiago to allow users to customize it's UI. I'm trying to remove the scrollbar in ContactsAdapter based on user preferences but nothing seems to work.

This is what I'm trying:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.list_content, container, false);
    view.setScrollBarSize(0);
    view.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
    view.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    view.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    view.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    view.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    return view;
}
// Even after all this the scroll bar stays the same
```

How can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view you've gotten a reference to in onCreateView is a parent in the view hierarchy of the ListView - not the actual ListView itself. I've tweaked your code to get a reference to the ListView itself.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.list_content, container, false);
    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    listView.setScrollBarSize(0);
    listView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
    listView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    listView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    listView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    listView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    return view;
}
```